# GX15 U4 BC InsertOrUpdate y problema con Nulls

Tags: genexus

Estoy realizando un "InsertOrUpdate" en una colección de "Compras" la cual es una transacción con un subconjunto de atributos de la tabla "Documentos".

Esto me está dando un error de clave foranea el cual adjunto al final con el atributo EmpleadorId el cual tiene la propiedad Nullable=true y no pertenece a latransacción Compras.

Veo que veo es que en el insert, está tomando todos los atributos de la tabla y no solo los de la transacción Compras.

Es conocido que en los BC no funciona "Empty as null", por lo que le agregue el atributo a la transacción y le establecí &Compra.EmpleadorId.SetNull(). Sigue dando el error...

¿Alguna pista?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Logré dejarlo funcionando. Como comenté, agregué el atributo a la transacción (aunque tiene la propiedad nullable) y lo tuve que agregar no visible a la transacción para que funcione correctamente el SetNull en el BC.

Rara la casuística pero quedo.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tambien podías solucionarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
&Compra.EmpleadorId = NullValue(EmpleadorId)
```